# Check if an array has an object who has a property that is an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, and I want to check if that array has an object whose property is an array.

E.g.:

```
array = [
  {
    data: [
      {
        data: [44, 66, 77],
        ids: 7468,
        names: "testststs",
      },
      {
        data: [33],
        ids: 7468,
        names: "testststs",
      },
    ],
    id: 2,
    name: "ssss",
  },
  {
    data: [
      {
        data: [44, 66, 77],
        ids: 7468,
        names: "testststs",
      },
      {
        data: [33],
        ids: 7468,
        names: "testststs",
      },
    ],
    id: 44,
    name: "tests",
  },
];
```

This array is dynamically generated and I could get the same array with the following object properties;

```
array = [
  {
    data: [1, 2, 344],
    id: 2,
    name: "ssss",
  },
  {
    id: 44,
    name: "tests",
  },
];
```

In the above 2 examples you can see that one has an object with a `data` property that is an array of objects and in the second one its  a data with simple array element.
Now I want to check whether the `array` with `data` property has a nested array or is a simple array of elements (like second example).

I know this way:

```
Array.isArray(array.data) && Array.isArray(array.data[0].data)
```

Is any better and more efficient method of checking available?

Comment: It's not clear the exact distinction you are trying to make. What if you have `data :[ {'a': 3}, {'b': 4}]` ?  That's neither a nested list nor a simple array of scalars.

Comment: What would be *better* in your opinion?

Comment: Just to be clear: this is not a somewhat recursive structure, right? It's just the 2 *layers*?

Comment: yes just 2 layers, no recurssive

Comment: Array.isArray should be the best way to check

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in many ways, and here's an example:

```js
var x = [{
    data: [{
        data: [44, 66, 77],
        ids: 7468,
        names: "testststs"
  }, {
        data: [33],
        ids: 7468,
        names: "testststs"
  }],
    id: 2,
    name: "ssss"
}, {
    data: [{
        data: [44, 66, 77],
        ids: 7468,
        names: "testststs"
  }, {
        data: [33],
        ids: 7468,
        names: "testststs"
  }],
    id: 44,
    name: "tests"
}];


var y = [{
    data: [1, 2, 344],
    id: 2,
    name: "ssss"
}, {
    id: 44,
    name: "tests"
}];


x.forEach(function (obj, i) {
    if (typeof obj['data'][0] === 'object') {
        console.log('x['+i+'][data] is an Array');
    } else {
        console.log('x['+i+'][data] is  notan Array');
    }
});

y.forEach(function (obj, i) {
    if (obj['data'] && typeof obj['data'][0] === 'object') {
        console.log('y['+i+'][data] is an Array');
    } else {
        console.log('y['+i+'][data] is not an Array');
    }
});
```

Comment: aww. didn't see this post is 2+ yrs old. btw I hope it will help someone a day.

Answer (score -1):

```
x?.forEach(({ data, id, name }) => {
  console.log(Array.isArray(data) ? "This is an array": "Not an array");
});
```

The a method used for both arrays.

Comment: He actually asked if "data" is a multidimensional array

Comment: This is incomprehensible. E.g., what is *"the a method"*?